# Is there a way to remove files from the default changelist in Perforce?

Tags: windows, perforce, p4v

I am using P4V to manage my files. I am also a recent user so I might not understand all the concepts well.

Sometimes I add some changed files to the default list then I change mymind and want to add them to another change list "later". So that my default list is empty at that moment.

I can move a file from the default changelist to another new one (even though I actually do not want to have a new change list atm)  Once I move it to another new changelist, the default list becomes empty. That is what I want, however the file is put back / resurrected in the default list if I empty the new changelist and delete that changelist.

Basically I want to be able to move my files out of default list, but i do not want to do any accidental "revert" as in reverting back to a previous version, because I will loose my work given those files are still in edit mode and not pushed to the server.

thanks

Comment: The file must be in *some* change list. Either the default change list or a numbered one. There is no such thing as a file checked out but not in any change list.

Comment: Another way to think of it is that the default changelist isn't really a changelist -- it's just the set of files that are open without a changelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file that is open is associated with either a numbered pending changelist or the "default" changelist (which is not really a changelist -- it does not have a number or a description and only exists as a sort of placeholder under which to show files in the UI that are open without a changelist).

If you want a file to be open, but not in the default changelist, you need to put it into a numbered changelist.  If you shelve the file, it is backed up to the server without being submitted.

If you want a file to be in neither the default changelist nor a numbered changelist, then the file can't be open at all; the only solution is to revert it.  If the file has been shelved, you can retrieve it from the shelf (unshelve it) at a later date.